# Associating non-linear three-time-point change with a continuous variable

Tags: time-series, panel-data, large-data, curve-fitting, growth-model

I would be incredibly grateful for help or advice regarding my following project:

- I have 3 time points (0, 30, 120 min) and complete data for about $n=500$ subjects for a continuous variable $M$. Individual time courses in $M$ over the 3 time points are highly variable and mostly non-linear. Thus, representing individuals by mean-M for each time point is not appropriate.
- What I want to analyse is: How does the longitudinal change in $M$ over the 3 time points predict a third variable (measured a 0min), called $IR$?
- In a third step, I would run the above analyses for about 200 variables $M$ in order to find out which among them (in terms of their longitudinal change) are associated with $IR$.

I am stuck to find an accurate summary value per individual (like a beta coefficient from linear regression if the Time-x-M association was linear) that I could use to predict $IR = a + (\text{summary_for_time_course_in_M})\times{b}$.

Equally, I am finding it hard to find an adequate model that captures the longitudinal association time-x-M in the first place: The associations are mostly non-linear and there is high inter-individual variation in curves.

Could anyone possibly help me with this or make suggestions? That would be really helpful!

P.S. As an analogy: If the change from 0 to 30 to 120min in $M$ was a straight line, I could calculated the slope Beta per individual. I could then in the second model use beta to predicted $IR$. Having done that for the 200 M-variables, I would rank them (by, e.g., F statistics, % Var explained, regression coefficient F-statistic), apply multi-testing correction, and end up with a select list of top M-variables significantly associated in time-course with $IR$.

This approach does not work, however, as the time-x-M association are not linear and variable between individuals.

Comment: I doubt this question is answerable in its current (vague) form. What are M & IR, eg? How could you possibly know something is "highly nonlinear" w/ just 3 points? Can you add more information about your situation, your data & your goals?

Comment: Hi, M is the intensity of a metabolite (measured by Mass spectrometry originally). IR is insulin resistance (measured as a continuous variable). It is an epidemiolgical study, where 500 subject had blood taken at 0/30/120 min that where each analysed by MS to evaluate the intensity of M. At time 0min, all subject also had the insulin resistance measured (once). There are about 200 metabolites and the question is: Which among them are significantly associated in their time course with insulin resistance?

Comment: Non-Linear means: E.g., for person 1, the intensity of M over three time points is 11-20-23. For person 2, it may be 22-19-43 etc. By non-linear, I mean "not a straight line over all three time points". But linear model between, 0/30, 30/120 are possible. Thanks!

Comment: With only 3 data, you can't differentiate between linear w/ high residual variance from curvilinear w/ 1 'bend' or 2 'bends'. You just don't have enough information. Is there some prior theory that describes these, or did you try a mixed effects model to see what it might show?

Comment: Hi gung, Unfortunately there is no prior hypothesis as to how the metabolite intentities change over time. I am generally not too confident with OLS regression modeling, as the individual time course vary quite a bit (i.e. comparing Spaghetti vs. mean plots). Does mixed effect modeling account for interindividual variations in time course? By mixed effects models, I have always understood combining random and fixed effects (I worked a lot with meta-analysis). Can you illustrate, what you mean in this context - thanks a lot!

Comment: A related question: If I can apply a mixed effects model or similar that includes more than 1 predictor (e.g, Metabolite intensity at 0, 30, and 120min in an additive model) - which statistics from this model would you recommend I than use to predict my actual outcome-of-interest (IR, insulin resistance)? IR = (metabolite change 0-30-120)*beta. What should I use to quantify (metabolite change 0-30-120)? Thanks again

Comment: I only meant looking at mixed models to see if there is any evidence for a curvilinear trend. As described, your data are perfectly consistent w/ a level mean & noise.

Comment: Thanks, gung. But what if, e.g., there are 250 subjects whose metabolite level is, on average 10-20-30 at 0/30/120min, and there are 250 for whom it is 20-10-0? Using the mean for each time point would be misleading, wouldn't it? Is there an a priori approach (not based on a posteriori grouping according to similar time trends) that would work?

Comment: You could try clustering on the random effects. Is there any reason a-priori to assume there are latent groups? It seems to me you have noisy data & you are making assumptions about what must have been the case.

Comment: Dear @gung, sounds interesting although I am not too experienced with cluster analysis. What do you mean by clustering on random effects? The simple model I originally discarded would be METABOLITE = alpha + beta*(Time) + error; where Time would be coded as "0/1/2" or "0/30/120". In step two, I could apply the beta weight to predict INSULIN RESISTANCE = beta*b1 + covariate*b2 + ... Where would I fit the random effects in? How do I cluster in them? Thanks!

Comment: What about the model: INSULIN RESISTANCE = Metabo0min + Metabo30min + Metabo120 + Covariates. I run that for every Metabolite, rank them by F statistc/Variance explained, correct for multiple testing and get my top Metabolite list associated with Insulin Resistance.

Comment: I don't think you are going to be able to learn these techniques on CV. You probably need to work with a statistical consultant.